# Client not query to referral DNS server (BIND 9, Centos 7)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I have two DNS Servers (Centos7) and one client PC (window 7).

localhost.beohu.com (192.168.2.254) and cent2.pimmup.com (192.168.2.253). With client PC' DNS server is 192.168.2.254.

**On localhost.beohu.com (192.168.2.254)**, the named.conf file is: (I cut irrelevant comment line)

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 192.168.2.254; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion no;
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
zone "beohu.com" IN
{
        type master;
        file "beohu.com.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN
{
        type master;
        file "192.168.2.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "pimmup.com"
{
        type master;
        file "pimmup.com.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "9.168.192.in-addr.arpa"
{
        type master;
        file "192.168.9.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
```

The zone files:

```
==> 192.168.9.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     cent2.pimmup.com.       hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       IN      NS      cent2.
253     IN      PTR     cent2.pimmup.com.

==> 192.168.2.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     beohu.com.      hostmaster.beohu.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       IN      NS      localhost.beohu.com.
252     IN      PTR     win7.beohu.com.
254     IN      PTR     localhost.beohu.com.

==> pimmup.com.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     pimmup.com.     hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       IN      NS      cent2.pimmup.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.2.253
cent2   IN      A       192.168.2.253


==> beohu.com.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     beohu.com.      hostmaster.beohu.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day


@       IN      NS      localhost.beohu.com.


localhost.beohu.com. IN A       192.168.2.254
win7.beohu.com. IN      A       192.168.2.252
```

---

**On the cent2.pimmup.com (192.168.2.253),**
The named.conf:

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 192.168.2.253; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
zone "pimmup.com" IN
{
        type master;
        file "pimmup.com.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "9.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN
{
        type master;
        file "192.168.9.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};
zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN
{
        type master;
        file "192.168.2.db";
        allow-update {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
};




include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Zone file:

```
==> 192.168.9.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     cent2.pimmup.com.      hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       IN      NS      cent2.pimmup.com.
254     IN      PTR     localhost.pimmup.com.
252     IN      PTR     win7.pimmup.com.

==> 192.168.2.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     cent2.pimmup.com.      hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

@       IN      NS      cent2.pimmup.com.
253     IN      PTR     cent2.pimmup.com.

==> pimmup.com.db <==
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     cent2.pimmup.com.     hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                        2001062501 ; serial
                        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                        3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                        604800     ; expire after 1 week
                        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day


@       IN      NS      cent2.pimmup.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.2.253
cent2.pimmup.com.      IN      A       192.168.2.253
localhost.pimmup.com. IN        A       192.168.9.254
win7.pimmup.com.        IN      A       192.168.9.252
```

---

From the client PC, if I set the DNS server is 192.168.2.253, it can resolve the win7.pimmup.com to 192.168.9.252 (and other A, PTR records also).

But my goal is: set the client PC' DNS to 192.168.2.254. When querying win7.pimmup.com (or other A,PTR record on pimmup.com domain), the DNS Server 192.168.2.254 return the referral value, in this case is 192.168.2.253.

From Wireshark on the client, I can see that the .254 response to the client query with an SOA of pimmup.com domain (please see the attached image). But somehow, the client does not use that SOA record to continue to send the query to that referral value, or do I need to do something else to make client request to the referral?

Sorry for the long post, but please help me to point out what should I do/change to make it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't configure the same bind instance to be both authoritative on some names and also recursing.  These two functions should be separated that will give you far less headaches in troubleshooting problems.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek, Any advice to make our goal work.?

Comment: See my first comment. Start by splitting recursive and authoritative services. As for the form, make your question more concise, concentrate on one case (one zone) having problems, otherwise it is just too long to read... You say also "please see the attached image" where there is none (but that is better, DO NOT use images, use text), and you should display proper `dig` results (don't forget about the `@`) because otherwise saying this answered that is tough to follow and may hide subtleties. The whole part about referral and SOA is explicitely not clear at all...

Answer (score 0):

### **192.168.2.254**

1. `listen-on port 53 { 192.168.2.254; };`  - this tells bind to only answer queries originating from the same computer that runs bind.
2. 

```
 ==> pimmup.com.db <==
    $TTL 86400
    @       IN      SOA     pimmup.com.     hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                            2001062501 ; serial
                            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                            3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                            604800     ; expire after 1 week
                            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
    
    @       IN      NS      cent2.pimmup.com.
    @       IN      A       192.168.2.253
    cent2   IN      A       192.168.2.253
```

Here, I can't see any `A` records for `win7.pimmup.com`, that's also one of the reasons why the domain name cannot be resolved.

3.

```
==> 192.168.9.db <==
    $TTL 86400
    @       IN      SOA     cent2.pimmup.com.       hostmaster.pimmup.com. (
                            2001062501 ; serial
                            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                            3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                            604800     ; expire after 1 week
                            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
    
    @       IN      NS      cent2.
    253     IN      PTR     cent2.pimmup.com.
```

`NS` record should contain an FQDN of the authoritative server. So, it should be `cent2.pimmup.com`, right?

### **192.168.2.253**

1. `listen-on port 53 { 192.168.2.253; };` - it tells bind to listen to queries coming from the same machine. (I'm surprised that it can resolve any domain from your client's PC because it's not listening to queries coming from the outside...)
2. `recursion yes;` - an authoritative nameserver shouldn't also be recursive. Read about [DDoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and [cache poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing).

### **General advice:**

1. What is the purpose of your servers? If you want them to be accessible from the outside, `listen-on` directive should be set to `{ any; }` or at least there should be some kind of [ACL](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/acl.html) defining which IP addresses are allowed to query it.
2. Consider [authoritative-only configuration](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#authoritative), because, as I pointed out earlier, the same server shouldn't be both recursive and authoritative, especially if it's publicly visible.
3. Since both of your servers are authoritative for the same zones, I strongly suggest you consider [master-slave configuration](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#master).

Comment: Hi Ves Bo, is there any way that if client (2.252) query the DNS SRV (2.254), then DNS SRV (2.254) return the value of CENT2 SRV (2.253). Then Client continue to query the CENT2 SRV (2.253) to get answer for pimmup.com.

Comment: I think you're referring to the recursive resolution of DNS queries and the delegation. Check out this link https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html and let me know if that's what you have in mind. :)